# Are HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY environment variables standard?

Tags: environment-variables, http, http-proxy

It seems that a lot of programs are designed to read these environment variables to decide what proxy to go through in order to connect to a resource on the internet. Those programs may also have their own, individual proxy settings, but if those are not set, they'll happily use these environment variables...

- HTTP_PROXY
- HTTPS_PROXY
- NO_PROXY

I just want to know:

- Are these environment variables standard?
- Is there a written specification (may be by the OS manufacturers?) that
  recommends the use of these environment variables?

Comment: I do not know no_proxy, but http_proxy (written lowercase ) is standard

Comment: @UweBurger perhaps you can state which programs use it.. And that goes for the questioner too. I've seen it used on wget

Comment: Documented (in a wiki) for Arch Linux: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Proxy_server&oldid=596484#Environment_variables

Comment: They are a _de facto_ standard. Despite their unixy origin, even [.NET uses them](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultproxy?view=net-6.0). There is some variability in the details of their support, though, as the excellent accepted answer explains.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I agree with BillThor's statement that *This is more a convention than a standard.*
I don't know the origin of these variables but in case of HTTP on *nix many conventions seem to originate from behavior of [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se) HTTP library and curl command line program.

At https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html there's description of environment variables related to using HTTP proxy which libcurl/curl understands:

> ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
>
> Curl reads and understands the following environment variables:
>   **`http_proxy, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY`**
>
> They should be set for protocol-specific proxies. General proxy should be set with
>   **`ALL_PROXY`**
>
> A comma-separated list of host names that shouldn't go through any proxy is set in (only an asterisk, '*' matches all hosts)
>   **`NO_PROXY`**
>
> If the host name matches one of these strings, or the host is within the domain of one of these strings, transactions with that node
>   will not be proxied.

Please notice that `http_proxy` is spelled lowercase as the only one among these variables. Some libraries/programs look for lowercase names of these variables whereas others look for upppercase names. To be *safe* one should define both lowercase and uppercase versions of each variable.

Another issue is that cited description of how host names are matched against `NO_PROXY` is not precise and does not answer the following questions:

- Should values be [fully qualified domain names (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) thus ending with a dot like `foo.example.com.` or not?
- Should `foo.example.com` match only this one domain or should it also match any subdomain like `bar.foo.example.com`? If the latter then should it also match any subdomain in any subdomain like `bar.baz.foo.example.com`?
- Is `.foo.example.com` (dot at the beginning) allowed and if so then what should it match ?
- Is asterisk (`*`) allowed as part of value (`*.example.com`, `*example.com`) and if so then how is it treated?

Lack of formal specification leads to confusion and bugs. Here one has to mention *libproxy* library which aims to provide correct and consistent support for proxy configuration. From project's home [page](http://libproxy.github.io/libproxy/):

> libproxy exists to answer the question: Given a network resource, how do
>   I reach it? It handles all the details, enabling you to get back to
>   programming.

Further reading:

- Issue I raised against curl – [Please document syntax and semantics of NO_PROXY environment variable.](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1208)
- Python's issue – [urllib: no_proxy variable values with leading dot not properly handled](https://bugs.python.org/issue29142) and related SO question – [Python 2.7.13 does not respect NO_PROXY and makes urllib2.urlopen() error with “Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41439233/95735)

Comment: What does libproxy have to say about the questions you raise? The one I'm interested in: "Should .foo.example.com match foo.example.com or not?"

Comment: I have no idea. I encourage you to ask at https://github.com/libproxy/libproxy/issues

Answer (score 21):

There is no real standard.

Different tools interpret these variables similarly but subtly differently. For example the *case* of the recognised environment variables and the *case-precedence* varies between tools like `curl` and `wget` and languages like Ruby, Python and Go: (This table is taken from the excellent article [We need to talk: Can we standardize NO_PROXY?](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/))

|  | `curl` | `wget` | Ruby | Python | Go |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `http_proxy` (lowercase) | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `HTTP_PROXY` (Uppercase) | No | No | Yes (warning) | Yes (if REQUEST_METHOD not in env) | Yes |
| `https_proxy` (lowercase) | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `HTTPS_PROXY` (Uppercase) | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `no_proxy` (lowercase) | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `NO_PROXY` (Uppercase) | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| Case precedence | lowercase | lowercase only | lowercase | lowercase | Uppercase |

For more  details (particularly about the NO_PROXY variable) and some history look at the mentioned [complete article](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/).

Comment: Can I say: insane? This is the kind of thing that drives people to absolute madness...

Answer (score 16):

This is more a convention than a standard.  It is likely supported by one or more protocol handler libraries which actually make the connections.  Java uses similar properties in its protocol libraries.

Understanding and using common conventions makes development much simpler.  It also helps implement the principle of least surprise and make programs more likely to `just work`.