# Best way to specify domain and all sub-domains in NO_PROXY?

Tags: bash, unix, proxy, environment-variables

Interpretation of the `NO_PROXY` environment variable [doesn't appear to be officially standardised](https://superuser.com/questions/944958/are-http-proxy-https-proxy-and-no-proxy-environment-variables-standard#). And most documentation for specific programs is fairly fuzzy about its exact interpretation ([e.g. emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/url/Proxies.html)).

This makes it difficult for me to answer one question I was curious about:

> Does `NO_PROXY=.example.com` match all of `example.com`, `subdomain.example.com` and `sub.domain.example.com`?

I want to set the `NO_PROXY` variable to match a bunch of main domains as well as all sub-domains of those main domains, in as many contexts as possible within my system.

Does anyone know *how* diverse the implementation of `NO_PROXY` actually is in practice? To achieve my goal, would I need to specify nothing less than the following for each domain?:

```
export NO_PROXY=example.com,.example.com,*.example.com
```

Comment: have you tried it using `curl` ?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez I don't remember if I used `curl` at the time, but `curl`'s implementation is largely irrelevant. I need to set the variable to be correctly interpreted by all clients, not juse `curl`.

Comment: Unfortunate I don't think there is a formal standard. I think each application may interpret it differently.

Answer (score 13):

For the the widest acceptance, use `.example.com` to specify a domain and all of its subdomains. Some implementation accept wildcards, many do not. But I think all support the dot.

Comment: `wget` does not IIRC: https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2021/01/27/we-need-to-talk-no-proxy/?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=blog